# Integrating over the rejection region to find average probability of Type II error for a range of values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

In Wackerly Mathematical Statistics the author states that you can only compute the probability of a Type II error for a single given specific value in the rejection region. Wouldn't it be possible to integrate over a range of values in the rejection region and find the average probability of a type II error?

Comment: If the rejection region is unbounded, it's hard to see how the result would be useful.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't integrate over an unbounded rejection region.

Comment: Not saying it can't be done. Saying it would be pointless to do so.

Comment: Why would it be pointless? You say it wouldn't be useful and it would be pointless but provide no justification. If you don't know the true value of the parameter and estimate the probability of a Type II error based on a single specific value then surely that is less informative than an estimate of the probability of a Type II error which does not assume the true value is some single specific arbitrary value.

Comment: For an infinite rejection region you could either integrate over the whole region (you can generalise average function value to infinite intervals) or you could integrate a certain number of estimated standard deviations away from the boundary of the rejection region thereby capturing the 'most likely' values.